# Is there a way to modify the fpdf output, so the name can be changed according to input by user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, pyfpdf

I am writing a program that takes input from a user in a variable called `client_name`; the method `output()` of the class `FPDF` does not allow me to change the file name of the PDF according to the `client_name` entered.
I've got the following code line to output my pdf file:

```
pdf.output(client_name".pdf ")
```

but it produces a syntax error.

Basically, I need that the file name of the PDF changes every time the client name change, please help.

Thanks

I've already tried entering this line `pdf.output(client_name".pdf ")`, hoping the pdf filename will change according to client name.

Comment: If `client_name` is a string. You need to add `+` for string concatenation: `client_name+ ".pdf "`

Comment: @Christina Tauauvea as @Marcelo Paco says use the instruction: `pdf.output(str(client_name) + ".pdf")`.

Comment: It works!!, thank you so much guys, I'm beginner at this coding stuff, hoping to learn as much as I can. :-)